# D3.js - Width of xAxis for a bar chart too short

Tags: javascript, visualization, d3.js

I created a bar chart ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDrQs/1/)) using D3.js.

I have one (probably very simple) question for which I would be glad to get some support:

Why is the x-axis too short?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older question, and my first answer attempt on Stack, but hopefully still useful:

From what I can tell your X domain only goes to XMax, which will be the bottom-left point of the last bar of the graph - it's not coming up "short", it just doesn't know how wide the bar is after XMax.

(It does not account for you adding the barWidth of 20 pixels, and your text placement does account for the additional width, which seems to be why you're seeing the problem only with the Axis.)

In order to extend the axis all the way to the end, you'll have to account for the additional barWidth in your domain, or append the additional barWidth another way. That might be possible by adding another half day or so on to your xMax, or by shifting each bar to the left of its X position (-barWidth) instead of +barWidth.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! That was the issue :) I created a new fiddle. Adding a third of a day did the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/GLSas/3/

Comment: Could somebody please give an example how to achieve this without the hack of adding another dummy data point?

Answer (score 0):

The x-axis isn't too short (it's exactly tall enough for your max value) but you might have wanted it to be [nice](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_nice).

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yMax])
    .range([h - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
    .nice();
```

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding yr problem. What is too short?

Comment: :) The xAxis is only drawn until shortly before the last bar. It (the black line) is missing the last few pixels. Somehow the scale for the axis and the drawing of the bars to not fit together.